# Default check radio with reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a radio group and I would like to initially have one checked

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  'test': new FormControl('AAA')
});
```

And the corresponding HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input name="test" type="radio" value="AAA" formControllName="test"> AAA   

   <input name="test" type="radio" value="AAA" formControllName="test"> BBB
</form>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-example-jyhfus?file=src/app/app.component.html)

I've initialized the fromControl with a value of `AAA`, but it doesn't check the first radio button. Any suggestions what is I do wrong here?

Comment: check your spelling 
formControlName not  formControllName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have sytax error. It's should be formControlName

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <input name="test" type="radio" value="AAA" formControlName="test"> AAA   
   <br> 
   <input name="test" type="radio" value="AAA" formControlName="test"> BBB
</form>
```